# How can I show hierarchy wise data in SAP HANA sp12 Calculation View

Tags: hana

I've a table say A_PRODUCT_MASTER with some columns say Level1, Level2, Level3.
Such that Level 1 being the parent node.
and Hierarchy is as follows:
Level1 -> Level2 -> Level3.
I want to show Level-wise Sale_qty. (sale_qty can be acquired from table say A_ITEM_SALES)

Comment: could you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Say my Level1 has values 100,200,300. Each of the level1 has sublevel Level2 say 100: a,b,c  200:d,e,f  300: g,h,i. And each Level2 has sublevel Level3 say a: 1,2,3   b:4,5,6 and so on. I want hierarchy like 100 --> a,b,c ----> 1,2,3.

Comment: When you write "I want to show" what exactly do you mean? Are you looking for a UI frontend representation of the hierarchy data or for ways to compute queries on hierarchies in HANA SQL?

Answer (score 1):

using SUM() [aggregation function using Partition By](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) clause can be an option.

Please check following SQLScript code with sample data

```
/*
create column table PRODUCT_MASTER (
Product varchar(30),
Level1 varchar(30), 
Level2 varchar(30), 
Level3 varchar(30),
Qty int
);

insert into PRODUCT_MASTER values ('SQLScript eBook', 'Book', 'Programming', 'Database', 10);
insert into PRODUCT_MASTER values ('Lambda', 'Book', 'Programming', 'Cloud', 5);
insert into PRODUCT_MASTER values ('NoSQL with DynamoDB', 'Book', 'Programming', 'Database', 3);
insert into PRODUCT_MASTER values ('SAP SD', 'Book', 'Software', 'ERP', 8);
insert into PRODUCT_MASTER values ('Mangala', 'Game', 'BoardGame', 'Traditional', 2);
*/

select
*,
Sum(Qty) Over (Partition by Level1) Lvl_1,
Sum(Qty) Over (Partition by Level1, Level2) Lvl_2,
Sum(Qty) Over (Partition by Level1, Level2, Level3) Lvl_3
from PRODUCT_MASTER
```

Output of this query will be as follows

[image]

I hope it helps, I'm not sure if you want to achieve this result

Comment: Thankyou ,what you have done is helpful. But, I've to achieve this in a calculation view when users come with hierarchial requirements. I've found a link where we can show hierarchies in Variables while viewing the data preview , but I'm unable to implement the same in my case. Will share the link here.

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/26/advance-hierarchy-modeling-with-sap-hana/  something likes this.

Comment: For Hierarchy data there are special hierarchy functions on SAP HANA database for developers, please refer to sample given at http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/query-hierarchy-data-using-sqlscript-on-hana-database.aspx tutorial

Comment: Uh, Oh! I guess my HANA SP12 doesn't support  these functions :-(

Comment: As far as I know SAP HANA 2 SP02 supports this Hierarchy feature

Answer (score 1):

@Prathamesh H,
I have prepared a second solution for you using [SQL RollUp](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/ms-sql-server-2008-t-sql-group-by-grouping-sets.aspx) clause.
You can also check for other aggregation functions like Group By Grouping Sets and Cube besides RollUp functionality on SQL

```
select distinct
    levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3,
    SUM(sums.Qty) as Totals
from (

    select
        distinct level1, level2, level3
    from product_master

    union all

    select
        distinct level1, level2, NULL as level3
    from product_master

    union all

    select
        distinct level1, NULL as level2, NULL as level3
    from product_master

) as levels
left join (
    select
    Level1, Level2, Level3, Qty
    from PRODUCT_MASTER
) as sums
    on  levels.level1 = sums.level1 and 
        levels.level2 = sums.level2 and
        levels.level3 = sums.level3
group by rollup ( levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3 )
having SUM(sums.Qty) > 0
order by levels.Level1, levels.Level2, levels.Level3
```

Output will be as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the question is mainly about computing queries on hierarchical structures (e.g. sum up revenue per org-unit), then using the [Hierarchy Functions](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/2969da89b87f4abd85fd0b5f9f5bc395.html) in SAP HANA 2 SP02 and newer would be the way to go.

On the UI side, you would need to use a frontend like [SAP Business Analytics for Office](https://www.sap.com/products/data-analysis-microsoft-bi.html) that understands and represents the hierarchical nature of the data.